# Overlaying Image on MKMapView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

This is all being done in Xamarin for iOS.

I have a `UIImage` of weather radar information. I need to overlay this image on top of a mapview. Not as an annotation but in a way that it will stay in place on the map and not stay in place on the screen. (The image should be centered on a lat & long, not on an x & y point on the screen)

I've googled this extensively but would be more than happy if someone finds a link I missed that solves my problem.

So far I have tried creating a custom MKOverlay and MKOverlayRenderer but am not sure on how to use the renderer. Below is a slightly stripped version of my custom overlay (if it is helpful). I'm also unsure of how to set the bounds in CalculateDerivedPosition().

```
public class RadarGroundOverlayBounds : MKOverlay
{

    public CLLocationCoordinate2D mOrigin
    {
        get { return _mOrigin; }
        set
        {
            _mOrigin = value;
            CalculateDerivedPosition(_mOrigin);
        }
    }
    public MKMapRect bounds
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public override MKMapRect BoundingMapRect
    {
        get
        {
            return bounds;
        }
    }

    public override CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate
    {
        get
        {
            return mOrigin;
        }
    }

    private const double EarthRadius = 6378137.0, Tau = Math.PI * 2, DegreesToRadians = 0.0174532925, RadiansToDegrees = 57.2957795;

    public RadarGroundOverlayBounds(CLLocationCoordinate2D origin)
    {
        mOrigin = origin;
        mWidth = 256;
        mHeight = 256;
    }

    public async Task<UIImage> GetImage()
    {
    }

    private void CalculateDerivedPosition(CLLocationCoordinate2D origin)
    {

        double latRadian = origin.Latitude * DegreesToRadians;

        const double degLatKm = 110.574235;
        double degLongKm = 110.572833 * Math.Cos(latRadian);
        double deltaLat = DEFAULT_RADAR_KM / degLatKm;
        double deltaLong = DEFAULT_RADAR_KM / degLongKm;
        //bounds = ;
        /*new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(origin.Latitude - deltaLat, origin.Longitude - deltaLong),
            new LatLng(origin.Latitude + deltaLat, origin.Longitude + deltaLong))*/
    }

    public class RadarOverlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer {

        public override void DrawMapRect(MKMapRect mapRect, nfloat zoomScale, CGContext context)
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(
                () =>
                {
                    UIImage image = ((RadarGroundOverlayBounds)this.Overlay).GetImage().Result;

                    DrawImgRotated(image, 0, context);
                }
            );
        }

        public void DrawImgRotated(UIImage image, float rotDegree, CGContext c)
        {
            c.SaveState();

            CGImage imageRef = image.CGImage;

            //loading and setting the image
            MKMapRect theMapRect = ((MapOverlay)this.Overlay).BoundingMapRect;//MKMapRect theMapRect    = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
            RectangleF theRect = (System.Drawing.RectangleF)RectForMapRect(theMapRect);

            //we need to flip and reposition the image
            c.ScaleCTM(1.0f, -1.0f);
            c.TranslateCTM(-theRect.Width / 8, -theRect.Height);

            // Proper rotation about a point
            var m = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(-theRect.Width / 2, -theRect.Height / 2);
            m.Multiply(CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((System.nfloat)(rotDegree * DegreesToRadians)));
            m.Multiply(CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(theRect.Width / 2, theRect.Height / 2));
            c.ConcatCTM(m);

            c.DrawImage(theRect, imageRef);

            c.RestoreState();
        }
    }
```